# Attempting to Update Database with Node.JS - 'UPDATE password SET password = NULL' at line 1"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, command-line-interface, mysql-workbench

OK, as you can see, I don't ask many questions here. I will do my best to structure it correctly. Please don't rip into my code too hard, I'm a student and learning.

I am trying to update my database with Node.js for a CLI I have been assigned to make (hence the use of Yargs). At one point I had the database updating with an auto-incremented id but no user or pass. Sadly, I can't remember what the code was at that stage.

#What I have Attempted#

To try and fix this I have tried a number of fixes. Due to my hesitation to ask here they're not logged. I know I have tried UPDATE and also moving the semi-colon around (all reasonable possibilities covered. Another thing I tried when hanging on in quiet desperation (it's the English way), was to use [0] and [1] after users (I had just remembered it was in an array and crossed it off my list).

Now I am out of options, so thought I would brave SO. Here's my code:

Connection.js = tested and fine

App.js:

```
//import and declare
require('./db/connection');
const { addUser} = require('./utils');
const yargs = require('yargs');
const command = process.argv[2];
const username= yargs.argv.user;
const password = yargs.argv.pass;
const title = yargs.argv.title;
const actor = yargs.argv.actor;
const watched = yargs.argv.watched;

const app = () => {
    if(command === 'add user'){
        addUser(username, password);
    }
    else(console.log('error'))
    //if (comnmand === 'add movie'){
    //     console.log('movie added');
    // }
}
app();
```

Index.js:

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const sql =require('../db/connection');
exports.addUser = (username, password) => {
    try {
        const user = [username, password];
        sql.query("UPDATE users SET username = ?; UPDATE password SET password = ?", user);
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Here's what I am giving to the CL:

```
node src/app.js 'add user' --username 'Mikey' --password '12345'
```

I have also browsed similar questions and hit Google.

EDIT:

I realised I was trying to pass in to a table I hadn't created (passwords). I changed the first 'password' to 'users' and it's the same story.

Error:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE users SET password = 12345' at line 1"
```

EDIT2:

```
const yargs = require('yargs');
const sql =require('../db/connection');
exports.addUser = (username, password) => {
    try {
        const user = [username, password];
        console.log("user data", user);
        sql.query("UPDATE users SET username = ?; UPDATE users SET password = ?", user);
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
       
    }
}
```

EDIT3 (Yargs updated):

```
//import and declare
require('./db/connection');
const { addUser} = require('./utils');
const yargs = require('yargs');
const command = process.argv[2];
const username= yargs.argv.username;
const password = yargs.argv.password;
const title = yargs.argv.title;
const actor = yargs.argv.actor;
const watched = yargs.argv.watched;

const app = () => {
    if(command === 'add user'){
        addUser(username, password);
    }
    else(console.log('error'))
    //if (comnmand === 'add movie'){
    //     console.log('movie added');
    // }
}
app();
```

Comment: Can you log the username and password values to the console ? The query is correct, and the error seems to point to a nullvariable

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Sorry for the silly question (I've been looking at code since 10am) but where would I put the log? I tried before and after the query but null joy.

Comment: After this line `const user = [username, password];` add the following `console.log("user data", user);` and see if it prints both the username and password values

Comment: No, it's not logging anything. Do you think it's my input?

Comment: update ypur question with the new code, you shouldn't get this error with your old code

Comment: you are using Yargs wrong. you call the params `user` and `pass` but then you call the script with `--username` and `--password`.

Comment: @nbk I updated the code. All that I have changed is the Yargs and the console log.

Comment: @nip Nice spot. Sadly, I am still getting the same error, however.

Comment: First we need to make sure the Yargs part is working - ie: the actual input values are being received in the script (this is why we use the logs, if they are null then there's an issue **before** the sql query). Then, you can also change the query to `sql.query("UPDATE users SET username = ?,password = ?", user);`. And note that this query is very **dangerous**, because you don't have a `WHERE` clause (you'll update ALL records everytime)

Comment: add a new user would be made by an INSERT INTO users (username , password) VALUES (?,== and the password sholuld always be hashed may another tutrial would help

Comment: @nip and there we have it. Thanks a lot for your help.